# Middleman sitemap.where doesn't exist

Tags: middleman, middleman-4

I'm trying to automatically generate a list of links to pages that have certain frontmatter in them, but every time I try to use `sitemap.where()`, I get a `NoMethodError`. For example, the following line:

```
 <%= sitemap.where(:title=>"about") %>
```

produces this output:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `where' for #<Middleman::Sitemap::Store:0x007f9b95c7d890>

Ruby    layouts/layout.erb: in block in singleton class, line 20
Web GET localhost/
```

I was wondering if I accidentally messed something up in my project, so I generated a new Middleman project, but I had the same problem when I tried to use `sitemap.where`. Is there a solution to this or another way that I can query all of the pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `where` method is part of ActiveRecord and might not work in Middleman.

To get only those pages in the sitemap which have a particular property, you can use Ruby's `select`:

```
<% sitemap.resources.select{|p| p.data.title == 'about'}.each do |page| %>
  <%= page.url %>
<% end %>
```

This code will print a (very basic) list of the URLs of pages that match your criteria.